# Supremum of a Sequence of Functions with a Simple Example

Tags: real-analysis

I've constructed the following minimal example because I am having trouble understanding the notion of supremum applied to sequences of functions. I understand the notion of supremum for sets, sequences and for an individual function, but a supremum of a *sequence of functions* seems like a different construction because it results in a function rather than a number. I want to be sure my intuition about it is correct.

Consider the identity function $f(x) = x$ and the  sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where each element $f_n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by simply taking derivatives, $f_n(x) := \frac{d^nf}{dx^n}(x)$. My inquiry was guided by the question, what should be $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n$?

It is easy to see that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = (x,1,0,0,\ldots)$. Also, it looks as though choosing $x$ to be certain values will influence what the supremum should be, for instance, if $x=-1$, then the highest number in the sequence above is $1$, similarly for any $x<1$. However, when $x>1$ it looks as though $x$ is going to be the highest value. Following this pattern leads us to reasonably take
$$
\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x) = \begin{cases} x,&x>1\\
1,& x\leq 1\end{cases}.
$$

So is this the way I should think about the supremum of a sequence? As the highest value $f_n(x)$ over all $n$ for a given fixed $x$?

Answer (score 1):

The supremum of a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is defined as :

$$\left(\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n\right)(x)=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (f_n(x))$$

I think your idea is correct.

Comment: It does seem right, but I'm still not satisfied because I can't find it in any books I have. Can you tell me where you found that definition?

Comment: The definition is intuitive, hence is not found in most textbooks. Think about how you define max of a finite set of functions. This is just its generalisation.